# refinerycms : issue loading images - production environment

Tags: image, refinerycms

I have a relatively simple refinerycms setup ( just getting started ), but have hit a problem loading images on my web page in production environment.

see http://saigos.net:3000 for where it works fine in dev ( webrick ) If I start the server in production with webrick, it also looks ok.

see http://saigos.net for where it doesnt work in production ( apache2/passenger )

Viewing the page source for each, I see ref to the image :

```
/system/images/W1siZiIsIjIwMTMvMTAvMTMvMTJfMTJfMjlfNTgwX3Rva3lvdG93ZXIuanBnIl0sWyJwIiwidGh1bWIiLCI0NTB4NDUwPiJdLFsicCIsInN0cmlwIl1d/tokyotower.jpg"
```

A file of this name obviously doesn't exist on the server, and I figure is being created dynamically in the page source by rails/refinery, I'm wondering if this can be used to help debug, but not sure where to take it.

I had a good dig around on the net, but only find examples of a similar problem where people are using Heroku and/or S3, neither which i'm using, and doesn't seem that the knowledge there can be applied to my case.

If anyone can give me mental nudge of what to check further, that will be appreciated, i've come to a bit of a dead end with this one.. :

Running :

Refinery CMS 2.1.0

sqlite DB on both dev and prod ( yes i know one is supposed to use something 'stronger' such as postgres in production, and i'll be exploring that once i fix this issue )

Rails 3.2.13
ruby 1.9.3p194

Ubuntu 12.10

Amazon EC2 micro VM ( not using S3 )

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.. after seeing this error in /var/log/apache2/error.log

[ 2013-11-23 11:49:53.3999 3060/7f5258d00700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 3083 stderr] cache error: Permission denied - /opt/refinerycms/saigo/tmp/cache/ABD

I changed the permissions on the file, and hey presto, the image now loads..